# how to serialize type object[,] in c#

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer, primitive

I am sure a very basic question. The ultimate aim is to take a range in Excel which will generally contain text and doubles and dump the contents into an SQL database.

I want to take the range (this is entered into the c# code as an `object[,]`) dump it into an XML string and save this directly into the database.

I have written a number of my own classes which I serialize easily using the `DataContractSerializer`.  However when it comes to serializing the `object[,]` I am running into a brickwall and a lot of searching the net just tells me how I can serialize more complex user defined classes which I already know.

Is it possible to serialize this primitive type ? And if so how ?

Comment: Why do you want to serialize them to xml? Wouldn't it be better to cast them across to the actual types and then store those against a proper database schema?

Comment: A number of reasons - some legacy, some wanting to re-use an existing table. The end Goal is to be able store the results of calculations that run as part of an overnight batch. These results can then be retrieved the next morning by users. The shape and nature of the results will Change depending on which calculation has been run. Using the serialization I can generically store and display the results, At least I could if I could serialize the range...

Comment: Assuming everything inside the array is a primitve (e.g. a value type), I'd recommend a beefier seralisation library, you could reference something like https://github.com/nessos/FsPickler - even though it's written in F#, you can call it from C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can't serialize multidimensional arrays using `DataContractSerializer`.

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Combining collection types (having collections of collections) is allowed. Jagged arrays are treated as collections of collections. Multidimensional arrays are not supported.

Switch from `object[,]` to `object[][]` which means from multidimensional array to jagged array.

Comment: Admitted - I can switch to using single dimension arrays - this is not the problem. Even if I have an `object[]` - its not clear to me how this is serialized by itself. If I create a class and I declare an `object[]` member of this class to be a `DataMember()` it will be serialized no problem.  However here I have a standalone `object[,]` that I want to serialize that is not inside a class. Can this be achieved or do I need to write a wrapper class around this ?

Comment: ??? I'm not sure that I understand you. Multidimensional arrays are not supported by `DataContractSerializer`. That's a fact. It doesn't matter whether it is contained in a class or standalone. You can't do that.

Comment: Vera - I can easily write my 2d Array into a 1d Array - and I am not tied to `DataContractSerializer`, neither of these are the issue. The issue is how to serialize the primitive object[] type using _any serializer.

Comment: @CraigRobinson stop! Now you're talking about `object[]` not `object[,]`. What are you trying to do? Do you want to serialize `object[]`? What does this array contain?

Comment: This question is being sent off topic, but for clarity - ultimately I want to serialize an `object[,]` - what I am trying to do is described clearly above. However - I can if necessary simplify the problem by decomposing the original `object[,]` into an `object[]`. The question may as well be how do I serialize an `int[]` or `double[]`. How can i serialize these primitive types in c# ? I cannot find anything describing this seemingly trivial Problem - only things to serialize a user defined class. Further I don't care which serialization is used, `DataContractSerializer` , `XmlSerializer` ?

Comment: @CraigRobinson I give up - sorry. I don't understand you. What is the problem of serializing `int[]` or `double[]` using `DataContractSerializer`? What did you try? `new DataContractSerializer(typeof(int[])).WriteObject(stream, new[] { 1, 2, 3 });` works fine. I haven't tested it using `double[]` but I think it will work the same way. Maybe you don't find anything about it because it works out of the box. Sorry but I'm not a native speaker and mabe I don't understand your requests. Sorry. I'm out.